# Is there a word for a process / technology which avoids "duplicated" work?

Tags: single-word-requests

The are multiple examples that share the common theme of allowing humans to (collectively) avoid repeating the same work.  I'm wondering if there is a word or term that captures this.  It's related to efficiency, and avoiding waste.  But it's the specific aspect of these technologies / processes / situations that completely negates and completely avoids duplicated work.  Examples:

1. scientific progress which is recorded, shared and recallable negates others have to repeat the same work.
2. collective knowledge bases like wikipedia avoid others having to research the same material
3. a master crafts person can produce a mould that can be reused a million times and prevent someone from having to form by hand the sculpture each time
4. if you take a piece of barren or polluted land and rejuvenate it, all subsequent generations can enjoy it without also having to perform the same work.
5. Stackexchange + search engines!  (the features that prevent / reduce asking the same question)
6. If a paper has referenced other work, no reader needs to do the work to find that reference as it's there (this contrasts to news papers which rarely give references so everyone has to try to repeat the same work).

I'm looking to say:

> the recording, sharing and recall-ability of knowledge (scientific, and community edited encylcopedic) is an example of a _ word _ process.

> a mould is an example of a _ word _ technology.

> providing a reference (citing your sources) is an example of a _ word _ practice.

It's like leverage.  It's like "deduplicating", but it is not the process of deduplication: which is to recognise duplicates and merge them / discard one.  Instead it occurs before the duplication event and prevents duplicate work for occurring in the first place.  It's perhaps related tangentially to the [Cornucopia of the Commons](https://wiki.p2pfoundation.net/Cornucopia_of_the_Commons).

Comment: "The are multiple examples that share the common theme of allowing humans to (collectively) avoid repeating the same work." Is meta-irony a thing?

Comment: 'Bloatless' can be found on the internet. But it's not yet in any dictionary as far as I can see. I suppose 'lean' is a possibility.

Comment: I haven't understood exactly what you're trying to convey, but here are some phrases that might help you: "there's no need to reinvent the wheel", "replicating X and Y's experimental results", "reducing the problem to one which has already been solved," "retracing our steps," "spinning our wheels," "work efficiently."

Comment: Thank you @aparente001 .  "there's no need to reinvent the wheel" is the closest.  The analogous concept in software, is the singleton, in that you only need one of it and for it to happen once.  Any further copies are unnecessary, wasteful and most languages prevent you from making them.

The application I'm interested in describing is act of referencing another piece of work.  If a paper has referenced other work, no reader needs to do the work to find that reference as it's there.  This contrasts to news papers which rarely give references so everyone has to try to repeat the same work.

Comment: @AJP - Here's another one you might like: *duplicate efforts*.

Comment: Yes it's exactly that word for the inherent property of a system, substance, structure, idea to negate duplicate efforts.